# Where is nix.conf located when installed on OSX?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, nix, nixos

I installed nix on osx using this command:

```
$ sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

Following instructions here:

https://hydra.nixos.org/build/119559243/download/1/manual/#sect-macos-installation

I'm trying to build a project that uses the nix shell and it's telling me to edit something in a file called nix.conf. However the project documentation was setup using a linux or nixos distribution so not sure where this file is located on osx. (The docs say to look in /etc/nix/nix.conf, but this file doesn't exist in osx)

Comment: You could try an exhaustive search `find / -name nix.conf 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/etc/nix/nix.conf` may not exist, you need to create it.

Comment: Tested with Catalina, you can use /etc/nix/nix.conf or, better, ~/.config/nix/nix.conf

Comment: But a.f.a.i.k. there are some things which can only be set in `/etc/nix/nix.conf`, like `trusted-users`: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/conf-file.html#conf-trusted-users